# Jenkins pipeline gives PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when writing global config file

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, aws-sam-cli

I am attempting to run a Jenkins pipeline in a Docker container. However, I keep getting a permission error when I do so.

- sam deploy --stack-name movie-crud-app-prod --template packaged-prod.yaml --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --region us-east-1 --s3-bucket aws-sam-cli-managed-prod-pipeline-artifactsbucket-bb8x5ri9c131 --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --role-arn arn:aws:iam::895120155967:role/aws-sam-cli-managed-prod-CloudFormationExecutionR-8LZ8IQHG754H

2023-03-13 01:15:33 Error when writing global config file: /.aws-sam/metadata.json

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "samcli/cli/global_config.py", line 326, in _write_config

File "pathlib.py", line 1273, in mkdir

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.aws-sam'

I have already tried changing the owner of the workspace directory to jenkins (with chown), as well as giving full read, write, and execute permissions to jenkins (with chmod).
[permissions of jenkins workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUVya.png)

I have noticed that new folders and directories created via the Jenkins pipeline do not have full write access to all users. I have tried using chmod g+s /path/to/parent to set all future folders and files to inherit permissions of the parent.
[permissions of new jenkins directories within workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCyHT.png)